# WordPress site migrated from old domain refuses to show images

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've migrated a WP site's files and DB over to new hosting at a new domain here:

http://s699410114.onlinehome.us/

Everything is good except images fail to load. I've done a search/replace on the DB and also cleared the cache. The image URLs look good (they have the domain name above) but the server responds with location:  and visiting the image directly immediately goes there, and the images don't show. Even an image that I added directly to this site and never lived on the old server doesn't show. We will soon set up the old domain to point to the new server but I wanted to show them the functional site before we did that and I've run out of ideas to get these images' location changed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the permission of the media folder after moving ? Is there any caching setting on your website/server ? I tried the direct link to an image but it got redirected to the main domain. For example: http://s699410114.onlinehome.us/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/slide3.jpg

Comment: I've not checked the folder permissions or any cache on the server itself. (I did clear the WP cache.) You are right that the images redirect to the main domain. You can see the redirect location in the image HTTP request. You don't see that on the equivalent image on the old host, which is still running. I wish I knew why moving the site would make WP put a redirect on images (and just to the base URL).

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, but I've set the URLs in the general settings by changing them in wp-config.php.

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit after much digging. I'm used to .htaccess in the root but the site had a second .htaccess in wp-content/uploads that redirected every HTTP request that didn't have the old URL as the referrer. I wonder what the point of that would be.